# Confused on making an array to store dots in the game Flood It

Tags: java

I have a class called DotInfo.java. This class has a constructor that has three parameters:

```
DotInfo(int x, int y, int color) {
    ...
}
```

There is another class called GameModel.java. I am trying to figure out how to store the instances of DotInfo in an array. As well i do not know what i need to increment **x and y** by to put circles on the board. Can anyone help?

This is my DotInfo class:

```
/**
* The class <b>DotInfo</b> is a simple helper class to store the initial color and state
* (captured or not) at the dot position (x,y)
*/

public class DotInfo {


private int x;
private int y;
private int color;
private boolean captured;


/**
 * Constructor 
 * 
 * @param x
 *            the x coordinate
 * @param y
 *            the y coordinate
 * @param color
 *            the initial color
 */
public DotInfo(int x, int y, int color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    captured = false;
}

/**
 * Getter method for the attribute x.
 * 
 * @return the value of the attribute x
 */
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

/**
 * Getter method for the attribute y.
 * 
 * @return the value of the attribute y
 */
public int getY(){
    return y;
}


/**
 * Setter for captured
 * @param captured
 *            the new value for captured
 */
public void setCaptured(boolean captured) {
    this.captured = captured;
}

/**
 * Get for captured
 *
 * @return captured
 */
public boolean isCaptured(){
    return captured;
}

/**
 * Get for color
 *
 * @return color
 */
public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

}
```

This is my GameModel.java class:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
* The class GameModel holds the model, the state of the systems. 
* It stores the followiung information:
* - the state of all the ``dots'' on the board (color, captured or not)
* - the size of the board
* - the number of steps since the last reset
* - the current color of selection
*
* The model provides all of this informations to the other classes through 
*  appropriate Getters. 
* The controller can also update the model through Setters.
* Finally, the model is also in charge of initializing the game
*/
public class GameModel {


/**
 * predefined values to capture the color of a DotInfo
 */
public static final int COLOR_0           = 0;
public static final int COLOR_1           = 1;
public static final int COLOR_2           = 2;
public static final int COLOR_3           = 3;
public static final int COLOR_4           = 4;
public static final int COLOR_5           = 5;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_COLORS  = 6;

private DotInfo[][] dots;
private int size;
private Random generator;

/**
 * Constructor to initialize the model to a given size of board.
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the size of the board
 */
public GameModel(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    dots = new DotInfo[size][size];
}


/**
 * Resets the model to (re)start a game. The previous game (if there is one)
 * is cleared up . 
 */
public void reset(){
    dots = new DotInfo[size];
    for (int i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<dots[i].length;j++) {
            dots[i][j] = 
        } 
    }
}


/**
 * Getter method for the size of the game
 * 
 * @return the value of the attribute sizeOfGame
 */   
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}

/**
 * returns the current color  of a given dot in the game
 * 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 * @return the status of the dot at location (i,j)
 */   
public int getColor(int i, int j){
    dot = new DotInfo(i, j, COLOR_0);
    return dot.getColor();
}

/**
 * returns true is the dot is captured, false otherwise
* 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 * @return the status of the dot at location (i,j)
 */   
public boolean isCaptured(int i, int j){
    dot = new DotInfo(i, j, COLOR_0);

}

/**
 * Sets the status of the dot at coordinate (i,j) to captured
 * 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 */   
public void capture(int i, int j){
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

}

```
/**
 * Getter method for the current number of steps
 * 
 * @return the current number of steps
 */   
public int getNumberOfSteps(){
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}

/**
 * Setter method for currentSelectedColor
 * 
 * @param val
 *            the new value for currentSelectedColor
*/   
public void setCurrentSelectedColor(int val) {
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}

/**
 * Getter method for currentSelectedColor
 * 
 * @return currentSelectedColor
 */   
public int getCurrentSelectedColor() {
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}


/**
 * Getter method for the model's dotInfo reference
 * at location (i,j)
 *
  * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 *
 * @return model[i][j]
 */   
public DotInfo get(int i, int j) {
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}
```

/**
     * The metod **step** updates the number of steps. It must be called 
     * once the model has been updated after the payer selected a new color.
     */
     public void step(){

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}
```

/**
     * The metod **isFinished** returns true iff the game is finished, that
     * is, all the dats are captured.
     *
     * @return true if the game is finished, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isFinished(){

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}
```

/**
     * Builds a String representation of the model
     *
     * @return String representation of the model
     */
    public String toString(){

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

```
}
```

}

Comment: Consider using a `List <DotInfo> list = new ArrayList<DotInfo>;`

Comment: I cannot use List unfortunately

Comment: So this is homework is it?

Comment: yes i need to get a kick start on this assignment but i dont know how to approach the model of the game its annoying me

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what your problem is but I try an answer anyway. I think the best for a flood it game would be an two dimensional array. So in GameModel you have

```
DotInfo[][] dotInfos = new DotInfos[ROWS][COLS];
```

and than fill it with two for loops:

```
for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++) {
        int color = ...; // Some random color
        dotInfos[y][x] = new DotInfo(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

But I would suggest to work without the DotInfo class since you would save the x and y information in two places - in the DotInfo class and in the index of dotInfos. So I would work with just

```
int[][] colors = new int[ROWS][COLS];
```

and

```
for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++) {
        colors[y][x] = ...; // Some random color
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking of the first way but didnt make sense of it